# vuex-module-decorators: Store not provided in decorator options when using dynamic option

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules, vuex-module-decorators

I'm new to Vue and I'm trying to use it as a front-end for an API I've built. I've been following multiple guides and reading through a lot of examples from various sources and nothing I've tried seems to work so I'm unsure where I'm going wrong.

Basically what's happening is when the page loads, I get an error in my browser's console:

```
Uncaught Error: Store not provided in decorator options when using dynamic option
```

The stacktrace tells me this is coming from my `Tags` module. What doesn't make sense is that I *have* provided the store object. If I try removing the `dynamic: true` from the module, I get a new error:

```
Uncaught Error: ERR_STORE_NOT_PROVIDED: To use getModule(), either the module
            should be decorated with store in decorator, i.e. @Module({store: store}) or
            store should be passed when calling getModule(), i.e. getModule(MyModule, this.$store)
```

If I don't use `getModule` and just export the class, I get a different error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: ERR_ACTION_ACCESS_UNDEFINED: Are you trying to access this.someMutation() or this.someGetter inside an @Action? 
That works only in dynamic modules. 
If not dynamic use this.context.commit("mutationName", payload) and this.context.getters["getterName"]
```

This error tells me I need the module to be dynamic and when setting `dynamic: true` again, I come back to the first error.

All the relevant code can be found below. Is anyone able to help me with this? I'm completely lost.

```js
// @/main.ts
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import './assets/app.css'

sync(store, router)

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

```js
// @/store/index.ts
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import tags from '@/store/tags'

export default createStore({
    state: {
        baseUrl: '/api/v1',
    },
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    modules: {
        tags,
    },
    plugins: [
        createPersistedState(),
    ],
})
```

```js
// @/store/tags.ts
import { Action, getModule, Module, Mutation, VuexModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators'
import HTTP from '@/http'
import store from '@/store'

interface Tag {
    foo: string
    bar: string
}

@Module({
    namespaced: true,
    name: 'tags',
    store,
    dynamic: true,
})
class TagsModule extends VuexModule {
    tags: Tag[] = []

    @Action({ commit: 'setTags' })
    async fetchTags(): Promise<Tag[]> {
        return HTTP().get('/tags')
    }

    @Mutation
    setTags(tags: Tag[]): void {
        this.tags = tags
    }
}
export default getModule(TagsModule)
```

Comment: The first thing you need to check in third-party libs is what version are they for. This one is for Vue2, while you obviously use Vue 3

Comment: @EstusFlask Well that's embarrassing if that's the case. I had seen someone recommend it to another person while I was searching up solutions for another problem. Nowhere does it indicate that it's specifically for Vue2 or not Vue3.
I don't suppose you can recommend another library? Vuex modules with Typescript's type declarations is an absolute mess.

Comment: If it doesn't indicate Vue version this means it was written when Vue 3 wasn't an option. This can be confirmed by vue version in lib's package.json and "Vue 3???" issues in the repo. I'm unaware of alternatives, and actually TS decorators themselves have type problems. You may want to check Pinia, it has TS-friendly api that is close to what Vuex 5 is expected to be.

Comment: @EstusFlask Gave Pinia a try quickly before I had to stop working on this and it seems to do the trick! Thanks for that.